# How to find max/min value in array of struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have Dataset structure defined as

```
struct Dataset: Hashable {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}
```

and then array

```
var dataset: [Dataset]
```

array is filled with values and I need to find max values for both x and y struct vars. Is use of

```
 let maxXValue = dataset.max(by: (Dataset, Dataset) throws -> Bool)
```

right approach and how it should look then?

Comment: What is a sin array?

Comment: @matt probably meant "in array"

Comment: Matt, obviously it's an array of the misdeeds a given developer has committed. :)

Comment: Yes, "in array" it was typo

Comment: What does it mean to find "max values for both x and y". Do you want to find a single record that has both the largest x and y value? What if one record has the max x value and a different record has the max y value? You have to define a programming problem before you can figure out how to implement a solution.

Comment: `Dataset` doesn't seem to be a correct name because it represents one element. Unless you call the `x` and `y` a dataset, in which case I'd expect plural `var datasets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `Sequence` and implement custom max and min methods to allow you to specify a keypath of a property that conform to `Comparable`:

```
extension Sequence {
    func max<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T)  -> Element? {
        self.max(by: { predicate($0) < predicate($1) })
    }
    func min<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T)  -> Element? {
        self.min(by: { predicate($0) < predicate($1) })
    }
}
```

---

```
let points: [CGPoint] = [.init(x: 1.2, y: 3.4),
                         .init(x: 0.1, y: 2.2),
                         .init(x: 2.3, y: 1.1)]
```

---

```
let maxX = points.max(\.x)
let maxY = points.max(\.y)
print("maxX:", maxX ?? "nil")
print("maxY:", maxY ?? "nil")
```

---

```
let minX = points.min(\.x)
let minY = points.min(\.y)
print("minX:", minX ?? "nil")
print("minY:", minY ?? "nil")
```

This will print

> maxX: (2.3, 1.1)
> maxY: (1.2, 3.4)
> minX: (0.1, 2.2)
> minY: (2.3, 1.1)

Answer (score 4):

`max(by:)` function will return the maximum *element* in the sequence, using the passed closure as the comparison between the elements.

So, you code will look like this:

```
let maxXValue = dataset.max { $0.x < $1.x }?.x
let maxYValue = dataset.max { $0.y < $1.y }?.y
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get two separate variables you can use `map` together with `max`

```
let maxX = dataset.map(\.x).max()
let maxY = dataset.map(\.y).max()
```

This will give you a tuple with the largest x and y values using `reduce` and `max`

```
let maxValues: (x: Double, y: Double)
if dataset.isEmpty {
    maxValues = (0, 0)
} else {
    maxValues = dataset
        .dropFirst()
        .reduce((dataset.first!.x, dataset.first!.y)) { (max($0.0, $1.x), max($0.1, $1.y)) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain in more detail with an example

```
struct Dataset: Hashable {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

let data1 = Dataset(x: 0.4, y: 0.2)
let data2 = Dataset(x: 0.3, y: 0.1)
let data3 = Dataset(x: 0.1, y: 0.6)

let dataArray = [data1, data2, data3]

let maxX = dataArray.max { (firstElement, secondElement) -> Bool in
    return firstElement.x < secondElement.x
}
let maxY = dataArray.max { (firstElement, secondElement) -> Bool in
    return firstElement.y < secondElement.y
}

print("Maximum X", maxX)
print("Maximum Y", maxY)
```